# parsing php array from backbone form post

Tags: php, backbone.js

I am posting form data to php and getting the response below, how can I turn this response into something I can use to set the form variables and send the email?

Here is the backbone collection calling process.php and posting the form data

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/postModel'
], function($, _, Backbone, postModel){
    var postForm = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: postModel,

    url: 'process.php',

    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        var postObj = {
            'name': $('#cmName').val(),
            'email': $('#cmEmail').val(),
            'website': $('#cmWeb').val(),
            'project': $('#cmProject input[type=radio]:checked').val(),
            'message': $('#contactMessage').val()
        }
        method = 'create';
        options.timeout = 100000;
        options.contentType = "application/json",
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.cache = false;
        options.data = JSON.stringify(postObj);
        return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
    },

    parse: function(response) {
        if(response != null) {
            if (typeof response.data !== 'undefined') {
                this.result = response.data;
            }
        }

        return this.result;

    },
});

return new postForm;
});
```

Form post from backbone.js app

```
{"name":"test","email":"test@test.com","website":"","project":"Web Development","message":"Testing."}
```

Response from php

```
array(1) {
  ["{\"name\":\"test\",\"email\":\"test@test_com\",\"website\":\"\",\"project\":\"Web_Development\",\"message\":\"$_POST$_POST$_POST$_POST$_POST$_POST$_POST\"}"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Here is the start of the php file:

```
<?php

parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$_POST);

 $_POST = var_dump($_POST);

//$name =
//$email =
```

Comment: json_decode would be a good start

Comment: Fix your JS so it assigns a proper variable name and puts the data in the data section, and then use [`json_decode()`](http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to figure out how to do, my post is fine php just isn't handling it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$json = '{"name":"test","email":"test@test.com","website":"","project":"Web Development","message":"Testing."}';

$obj = json_decode($json);

$name = $obj->name;
$email = $obj->email;
$website = $obj->website;
$project = $obj->project;
$message = $obj->message;

?>
```

Comment: thanks, yes that is what I need to do but first I need to object to be formatted correctly but there are issues with backbone and php

Comment: What kind of issues? (we wouldn't know unless you state it in your question)

Comment: The response from the php is how the object is coming in on the backend when it is being posted correctly as json

Comment: I know.  This is an issue with backbone posting Json in php, I am posting here to see if someone has a method to fix this.